# jenkins use kubernetes plugin to deploy slave ，but in the slave containers，can not use kubectl

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl, slave

I use jenkins k8s plugin to deploy slave node，but in the slave container，can not use kubectl，the error is ：

> User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Nearly, I done a thing like `docker run a slave` , but it's ok, the docker containers can use kubectl, why?
thanks!

Comment: Please start your investigation with `kubectl get roles,rolebindings,sa`. Could you please provide more details (environment parameters, jenkins deployment and steps to reproduce this issue?) Please provide your env details as **yaml** outputs. You can use also `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a role for cluster-admin for your user:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding permissive-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=admin --user=kubelet --group=system:serviceaccounts
```